# ActiveRecord `belongs_to` for primary key types other than integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake

So I have two models, `location` and `menu`. Each `location` can have many menus but each `menu` has only one `location`.

I am using `string` type for my `location` ids. However I can't get `rake db:migrate` to generate a correct schema with `string` type for the foreign key on the `menu` table.

models:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :id

  has_many :menus
end

class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

migrations:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :locations, id: false do |t|
      t.string :id, primary_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateMenus < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :menus do |t|
      t.belongs_to :location
      # other stuff
    end
  end
end
```

result in this schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180413142949) do
  create_table "locations", primary_key: "id", id: :string, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
    create_table "menus", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "location_id"
    t.text "name", null: false
    # other stuff
    t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_menus_on_location_id"
  end
end
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where does `"levelup_id"` in your locations table come from?

Comment: That was a mistake copy pasting stuff, just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to modify your migration for the `menus` table. Have you tried something like this?

`t.references :locations, type: :string, index: true`

Or:

```
class CreateMenus < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :menus
    add_reference(:menus, :location, type: :string, foreign_key: true)
  end
end
```